# Grouping custom field sets into one Tab?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

As we grow, the number of custom field sets keeps growing and getting added onto.

We add each new custom field set as a TAB, which works okay, except this number of tabs keeps growing.

Is there a way to group several custom field sets together, and then have them all appear under one tab?

EXAMPLE:
We have 6 custom field sets.
Three of the custom field sets contain legacy data, that is really not used anymore, but is there "just in case".
It would be great if I could create a new TAB called LEGACY and then these three field sets would appear under that legacy tab.

There are also other custom field sets that would make sense to group together as well.

From what I can see this is not possible currently, so I guess this becomes a Feature Request!

Comment: and you don't want to Collapse the Legacy ones and have them at v bottom of the Summary page?

Comment: No I do not want them at bottom of Summary page (collapased or open). There is just too much information to try and keep on summary page, so tabs is better choice for us. Grouping custom field sets under a tab would be even better though ;)

Comment: Sure. i just wondered if collapsed at bottom then they are pretty much out of sight.

Answer (score 2):

you could create a searchkit for each custom group and add them in formbuilder and include it on contact summary page